# Animated object when hovering over not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, mouseover

This is the problem. I have a square div and I animated it (in CSS) to slide down the page. I also made the div to disappear (in JavaScript) when I hovered over it. If I keep the mouse still without moving it when the div slides under the mouse it doesn't register that I am hovering over it and nothing happens. If I move the mouse the smallest bit then it realized that I'm hovering over it. Here is a JSFiddle to explain my issue. 
https://jsfiddle.net/z4q45Laz/1/
Here is my HTML

```
!DOCTYPE HTML
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  <head
  <body>
    <div class="square" id="square" onmouseover="test()">

    </div>

    <script>
    function test(){
        document.getElementById("square").style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my css

```
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -webkit-animation: blockMove 4s linear infinite; 
  animation: blockMove 4s linear infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes blockMove{
   from {top: 0;}
   to {top: 90%;}
}

@keyframes blockMove{
   from {top: 0;}
   to {top: 90%;}
}
```

Comment: Does css solution (https://jsfiddle.net/z4q45Laz/2/) solve your task?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it with just css, here the code:

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -webkit-animation: blockMove 4s linear infinite; 
  animation: blockMove 4s linear infinite;
}
.square:hover {
 background-color: red;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blockMove{
   from {top: 0;}
   to {top: 90%;}
}

@keyframes blockMove{
   from {top: 0;}
   to {top: 90%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  
  </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't fix my problem. The first reason it won't work is because it doesn't stay red. It changes back to green. At least with the JS I had it didn't change back. Also it does the same thing with the hovering. Here is a gif that might explain it better. http://imgur.com/IdUw3nJ  Notice how the first time it moves under I don't move the mouse and nothing happens. The second time I move the mouse and it works. Is there a way to fix this so it will work if even the mouse is still and if not is there a workaround?

Comment: Now I'm from phone. But I have understand you can fix it using not .square:hover but using this code and change .square:hover with .square:active. I am not If work but should be. Ir doesn't work tomorrow I fix.

Comment: That only works if you click on it. But that completely defeats my purpose. I would like it to work when the div is under the mouse. Even if the mouse isn't moving.

Comment: Was I not clear enough? Is there something you don't understand? If so please let me know.

Comment: Yes, I don't know when the box must be red. At the hover or the click?

Comment: At hover! It works when I move the mouse over it but if I keep the cursor still and the div slides (because of the css animation) under the cursor then nothing happens. How can I make it realize that I'm hovering over it even when my cursor is still